# Multiple Forms and Formsets in CreateView

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-class-based-views

I have 2 models, `Father` and `Son`.

I have a page to register `Father`. On the same page I have a formset to register `Son`.

On page has a button "more" to add another `Father` and their respective `Son` on the same page.

Does anyone have any examples using `CreateView`?

Comment: I tried the solution given by Burhan, but ran into some problems, including the one mentioned by avances123. Then I found this blog post: http://kevindias.com/writing/django-class-based-views-multiple-inline-formsets/ which worked.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Class based views are still new, so I'll write this out. The process is simple:

First, create the forms for your objects. One of the forms will be repeated. Nothing special to be done here.

```
class SonInline(ModelForm):
    model = Son

class FatherForm(ModelForm):
    model = Father
```

Then, create your [`formset`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/forms/formsets/):

```
FatherInlineFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Father,
    Son,
    form=SonInline,
    extra=1,
    can_delete=False,
    can_order=False
)
```

Now, to integrate it with your `CreateView`:

```
class CreateFatherView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'father_create.html'
    model = Father
    form_class = FatherForm # the parent object's form

    # On successful form submission
    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('father-created')

    # Validate forms
    def form_valid(self, form):
        ctx = self.get_context_data()
        inlines = ctx['inlines']
        if inlines.is_valid() and form.is_valid():
            self.object = form.save() # saves Father and Children
            return redirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(form=form))

    # We populate the context with the forms. Here I'm sending
    # the inline forms in `inlines`
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        ctx = super(CreateFatherView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            ctx['form'] = FatherForm(self.request.POST)
            ctx['inlines'] = FatherInlineFormSet(self.request.POST)
        else:
            ctx['form'] = Father()
            ctx['inlines'] = FatherInlineFormSet()
        return ctx
```

Finally, here is the template:

The key part is the jquery [django-dynamic-formset](http://code.google.com/p/django-dynamic-formset/source/browse/trunk/src/jquery.formset.js?r=14) plugin that keeps adding new inline forms:

```
<form id="father-form" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" action=".">
{% csrf_token %}
<div class="row">
  {% for f in form %}
    <div class="span3">{{ f.label }}<br />{{ f }}
      {% if f.errors %}
          {% for v in f.errors %}
            <br /><span style="color:red;">{{ v }}</span>
          {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    </div>
 {% endfor %}
</div>
<hr />
<h2>Sons:</h2>
<table class="table-striped">
 <table>
 {%  for f2 in inlines %}
   <tr id="{{ f2.prefix }}-row">
      {% for i in f2 %}
        <td>
           {{ i }}{% if i.errors %}<span style="color:red;">{{ i.errors }}</span>{% endif %}
        </td>
      {% endfor %}
   </tr>
 {% endfor %}
</table>
{{ inlines.management_form }}
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Go Go Gadget &rarr;">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#father-form tr').formset({
            prefix: '{{ inlines.prefix }}'
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: This does not call formset.save() so no sons are saved.

Comment: sons not saved as well