# More GenericViews in one Template

Tags: django

In my model I have definde two Tables:

Bill and delivery

I want one Template with the BillCreate - Form, and up to five times the Delivery create from.

Is it possible to show the generic CreateViews, in one template?
How to add the Form for the delivery with a button "add delivery"?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Forms and Formsets in CreateView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573992/multiple-forms-and-formsets-in-createview)

Comment: I use ClassBasedViews. Now I don't know where to define my Formset

Comment: You can also use [inlineformsetview](http://django-extra-views.readthedocs.org/en/latest/views.html#inlineformsetview) from [django-extra-views](http://github.com/AndrewIngram/django-extra-views).